# Question still didn't receive a good answer after bounty?

Tags: support

This is pretty simple to understand: it is when someone would have a question, place a bounty, and not receive a working/good answer. This has happened to me a couple of times, and I want to get an answer. I can't create a duplicate, I can't place a second bounty, what would I do? Would I delete it and duplicate it? I am confused. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: that is a sure sign that your question is: 1 not clear, 2 a hard or unusual problem, or 3 very localized

Comment: You can't assume that just because you put a bounty on something, that you'll get a good answer. When I look through the bounty section, I never see something that I could answer. Like @David if your answer isn't easy to understand, or is something that not many users know about, putting a bounty on something won't help. Everyone here is happy to help, but we need something to work with.

Answer (score 6):

A bounty isn't a good answer generator.

All a bounty does, is bring more attention to the question, and give a bit of incentive for it to be answered.

For a question to be answered, it needs to be easy to understand, and it needs to have enough people who understand that part of Blender.

A bounty will do absolutely nothing if the question it's self isn't good.

Comment: Well I got comments of people saying they *see* the issue but *dont know how to solve it*.

Comment: @blackhole That suggests that it's a part of Blender that people don't know very well.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately merely placing a bounty on questions doesn't guarantee or entitle us to get an answer. It's there to entice people to spend a little time figuring out if they can solve it *for you*, or make it worth their time. You might imagine that some questions are not necessarily easy to answer, even if the question is clear.

Anyone who knows how to answer, and has read your questions, will have tried to answer, most of us probably read the question and know that we can not answer due to lack of expertise in the Game Engine.

Simply deleting your Question and adding the question back as a new question won't be any better. Sometimes very short questions require literally paragraphs of text to put across a meaningful solution. Conversely, very long questions are a pain to read and a sign the question hasn't gone through a lot of self-editing. If that's the case we've asked you to re-word your question or clarify things, or break the question into smaller separate issues because stack-exchange isn't about answering 5 questions at a time.

If the question is clear, remember that we all volunteer our time, someone might eventually stumble into the question and be able to give a satisfying answer. Or up your bounty, 50 is very little.

Comment: I was planning to use more bounty points, but I recently opened 3 bounties and only got 1 solved (no rep left).